# WmiPrvSE.exe using lots of RAM

Tags: windows-server-2008

I've got a server running Windows Web Server 2008 SP1 (Version 6, Build 60001, SP 1).

Looking in task manager I've got an instance of WmiPrvSE.exe running under the SYSTEM account using more than 400MB of RAM in its Working Set.

How can I find out what this is and why its using so much RAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is the HP Network monitor.